# Gauge invariance for a Lagrangian density with a mass contribution

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, mass, gauge-invariance

Consider the free Maxwell Lagrangian density:

\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L} = -\frac{1}{4}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu} + \frac{m^2}{2}A^{\mu}A_{\mu}
\end{align*}
Where we added a mass contribution $m$. And sign convention $(+,-,-,-).$ Now my question is:

> **How can one find all the values of the mass $m$ for which this Lagrangian density is gauge invariant?**

I already know that by replacing the derivative with the covariant derivative:
\begin{align*}
D_\mu = \partial_\mu +ieA_\mu
\end{align*}
I can include the gauge invariance into the Lagrangian. However, in this Lagrangian I don't see any derivative term so I cannot perform this transformation. I also thought about the following transformation:

\begin{align*}
&\psi \rightarrow e^{i\theta} \psi\\
&A_\mu \rightarrow A_\mu-\frac{1}{q} \partial_\mu \theta
\end{align*}
But there is also no wavefunction $\psi$ in the Lagrangian density. I still think that I need to do some kind of transformation and then check if $\mathcal{L}$ is gauge invariant but I don't really know the conditions of a Lagrangian density being gauge invariant.

Comment: You do realize the field strength contains derivatives right? So given this fact and the last transformation rule (the one for the gauge field), what does a transformation give you?

Comment: So I tried this: $F^{\mu\nu} \rightarrow D^\mu (A^\nu-\frac{1}{q} \partial_\nu \theta)-D^\nu(A^\mu-\frac{1}{q}\partial_\mu \theta) = (\partial^\mu +ieA^\mu)(A^\nu - \frac{1}{q} \partial_\nu \theta)- (\partial^\nu +ieA^\nu)(A^\mu - \frac{1}{q} \partial_\mu \theta)$ and $\frac{m^2}{2}A^\mu A_\mu \rightarrow \frac{m^2}{2}(A^\mu -\frac{1}{q} \partial^\mu \theta)(A_\mu - \frac{1}{q}\partial_\mu \theta)$. Are these the right transformations ?

Comment: $F^{\mu\nu}$ is gauge invariant, isn't it? You only need to worry about the second term.

Comment: Those look fine.

Comment: f I only focus on the second term (the one with $A^\mu A_\mu$) I get this after transforming:

$$\frac{m^2}{2}[A^\mu A_\mu-\frac{1}{q}A^\mu \partial_\mu \theta - \frac{1}{q}A_\mu \partial^\mu \theta + \frac{1}{q^2}\partial^\mu \theta \partial_\mu \theta] $$

I'm a bit unsure whether I should also transform the derivative in this expression to $D_\mu$. Furthermore I'm confused how to know when this expression is gauge invariant.

Comment: 1) You should not use the covariant derivative in there. 2) How was gauge invariance defined for the first term? Or for that matter, how is it always defined?

Comment: We have seen this definition in class for gauge invariance: "Now we insist on our theory to be gauge invariant and this implies that the matrix elements do not change under a gauge transformation." Does this mean that the 3 last terms have to be equal to zero in order that  $A^\mu A_\mu$ is gauge invariant? I don't really see how this will be the case for some values of m (except when m=0)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if this Lagrangian density $L$ is gauge invariant, you can make the transformation:
$$A_\mu -> A_\mu + \partial_\mu \lambda$$
And check whether or not the Lagrangian density you get ($L'$) is the same as the original one.
For your question, you get:
$$L' = -\frac{1}{4}F^{\mu,\nu}F_{\mu,\nu} + \frac{m^2}{2}A^\mu A_mu + \frac{m^2}{2} (\partial^\mu \lambda)((\partial_\mu \lambda)) + \frac{m^2}{2} A^\mu(\partial_\mu \lambda)$$
You can rewrite this as:
$$L' = L + \frac{m^2}{2}[(\partial^\mu \lambda)A_\mu + (\partial^\mu \lambda)(\partial_\mu \lambda)+A^\mu(\partial_\mu \lambda)]$$

When does $L$ equal $L'$? For $m=0$.